DataGridView AutoGeneratingColumn event property not found
I am attempting to add the "AutoGeneratingColumn" event to a DataGridView control programmatically:
DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
dataGridView1.AutoGeneratingColumn += dataGridView1_AutoGeneratingColumn;

Compiler gives error:
error CS1061: 'DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'AutoGeneratingColumn' and no accessible extension method 'AutoGeneratingColumn' accepting a first argument of

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Tried searching web for answer. I get plenty of examples for what the event handler should look like, but none show how to bind event handler to instantiation of DataGridView control variable.

See DataGridView docs. There are AutoGenerateColumns Property and AutoGenerateColumnsChanged Event.

See xxx Doc  Always the best first step when something doesnt work quiet as you expected including unexpected error messages.  There is also a ColumnAdded event (See Docs) which gets fired as it auto generates columns.  It lets you intercept and tweak certain columns as needed.

Don't you make use of an IDE that provides an auto-complete feature, so when you press the dot, you have the full list of properties, methods, events etc. associated with the object? Visual Studio Community edition is free software, just in case

This event is defined in System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid class, maybe you confused the two?
